# Oracle's function created via jdbc is in an invalid state

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

When I create Oracle's function in SQL Developer everything is ok, but when I create the same function via jdbc it is in invalid state

Here is the function sample:

```
create or replace function TEST_FUNC return number is
begin
    return 100;
end;
```

Java code:

```
Connection con = ...;
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.execute(sql);
```

When I execute function:

```
select TEST_FUNC() from dual;
```

I get error: ORA-06575: Package or function TEST_FUNC is in an invalid state

Can you explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well, did you look at see what the errors are on the function?

Comment: `select * from user_errors where name = 'TEST_FUNC'`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff It gives: "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:
   begin function package pragma procedure subtype type use
   <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> form
   current cursor external language
". When I create the same function in SQL Developer this query doesn't show any errors.

Comment: @ako you have a mistake in the Java Code that is building the String that is populating your sql variable - post the actual java code that is building the sql variable being passed to stmt.execute(sql).  That is where your " Encountered the symbol """ is coming from.  Just do a System.out.println(sql) - it will probably jump out at you what the mistake is when you try to compile that output in SQLDeveloper.

Comment: @Brian I read sql from file using freemarker. I posted text of file in my question. When I copy-paste it into SQL Developer function is created and executed without any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function needed to be complied to use them. Not compiled function gives this exception. Also make sure you do not have any terminating CR/LF in your query. Copy it to a text editor (textpad) to see if you have any.

Comment: How to compile function via jdbc? I've tried stmt.execute("alter function TEST_FUNC compile") but it didn't help.

Comment: Yes, I have CR/LF in query, because I read it from file. Are they forbidden in oracle?

Comment: I would say, yes. I prefer to give it a try, though.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. After removing all CR/LF function works.

Comment: Thank you. This save my day